# Javascript for conflicting Checkboxes in PDF

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have a single condition where if A1 box is already checked and B1 is checked (or vice versa) that an alert is thrown and B1 is unchecked.
Updated code below:

```
       // Document-level function 
   function validate() {
       if (document.getElementById('a1').checked = true & document.getElementById('b1').checked = true;
   } {
       app.alert({
           cMsg: "Sorry...",
           nIcon: 1
       });
       document.getElementById('b1').removeAttribute('checked');
   }
```

Comment: OK trying to only figure out that if A1 and B1 are both checked at the same time, both true, that an alert pops up and only B1 is unchecked. I'm validating on jsfiddle but the best I have gotten anything to work was that when I either checked or unchecked either box the alert would get thrown.

Answer (score 0):

If the checkboxes A1 and B1 are mutually exclusive (meaning that they can not be checked at the same time), there is no need at all for JavaScript.

Simply give those two fields the same name with different return value.

And that's it…

Comment: Hmm. I think I see what you mean, but if both are checked at the same time, I need it to still popup a prompt to alert the user. I also can't name them the same or else when one is checked, it will check the other.

Comment: With the described method (same field name, but DIFFERENT return value) it IS NOT POSSIBLE that both boxes can be checked (that's why the condition is that the options assigned to the check boxes are mutually exclusive). Because it is not possible to check both boxes, you don't need a message to warn the user. Also, the return value must be different, otherwise, the boxes do indeed check in synch.

Comment: I'm a tad confused. I'm using two different field names, and I can check them both on the form. The goal is that rather than lay a line of text in the document that says A1 + B1 is not permitted, I want to alert the user instead and also remove the checked attribute for B1. I can't just make it impossible, I have to briefly explain why to the user. Hopefully my updated code looks better... Also, I am assigning both checkboxes that this condition applies to, to run this JS on mouseUp. Am I doing that right?